# A website with a whole bunch of columns of varying sizes?

Tags: layout, size, varying

Is there a way to have a lot of columns of vary sizes? Basically I want it to look a certain look but I feel I've been hacking at it to look a certain way and I was wondering if there was a more standards correct approach. For example I was going crazy to get the border line the black line to fill up the whole width of the space(the container) after the header div and that was a disaster. I have an image of what I wanted it to look like and I will jsfiddle what I have coded. I know my coding is a bit of a disaster as this was more a project where I wanted to see if it could be done. Sorry!

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/8tUEB/)

I don't even know if float is a good property to be using as it doesn't seem to take up the whole box before dropping to the next line. There are also some measurements(also an image) that I went by(somewhat to get everything kind of symmetrical. Not that it necessarily ended up that way.

[What I want it to look like](http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/5763/designweb.png)

Unfortunately I cannot post the measurement image since I am only allowed 2 links because of low reputation. But I guess that would be the least of my issues as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this with the [grid system of Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html). It enables you to create a multi-column layout with varying column widths by using some nested divs and a few classes.

Comment: So would this would allow multi-column and to have the divs aligned in a grid structure?